# String methods .repeat()

Tags: javascript

```
for(let i=1 ; i <=5 ; i++){
  console.log("i".repeat(i));
}
```

and the result of this is;

```
i
ii
iii
iiii
iiiii
```

in different lines in console.log()

what task is .repeat(i) performing in this loop and why it breaks a line?

I asked my Ai(snapchat) to give input of following program now I am confused with this .repeat()

Comment: It doesn't *"break a line"* it outputs five separate values. Each iteration of the loop runs a `console.log()`

Comment: You can search for `repeat` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/). You will save yourself a lot of time when you learn to rtm yourself.

Answer (score 4):

> what task is .repeat(i) performing in this loop

From [the MDN article about `.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

> The repeat() method of String values constructs and returns a new string which contains the specified number of copies of this string, concatenated together.

---

> why it breaks a line?

Because when you call `console.log`, it prints what you send it and then moves to the next line - if you want it to do something else, you'll have to decide what you want it to do and think of another solution. What do you want it to do?